# Hibernate mapping and Unique index or primary key violation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, h2

I am new in hibernate, and I am experiencing the following problem. "Unique index or primary key violation". The problem appears due to the wrong mapping, but I spend hours to figure out why it is happening.

I have one super class called DataStructure

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class DataStructure {

private int DS_ID;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public int getDataStructureID()  {
        return DS_ID;
    }
```

Then the class Association which associate two elements. Some parts of the class are omitted here, just to simplify it.

```
@Entity
public class AssociationTemporal extends DataStructure {

    private DataStructure elementA;
    private DataStructure elementB;

    @OneToOne
    public DataStructure getElementA() {
        return elementA;
    }
    public void setElementA(DataStructure elementA) {
        this.elementA = elementA;
    }

    @OneToOne
    public DataStructure getElementB() {
        return elementB;
    }
    public void setElementB(DataStructure elementB) {
        this.elementB = elementB;
    }
}
```

This class serves as middle class between two classes of DataStructure type. Like this.

TP-Association-TP

TP class:

```
@Entity
public class TP extends DataStructure {

    List<AssociationTemporal> listOfAssociatedTPs = new ArrayList<AssociationTemporal>();

    @OneToMany
    public List<AssociationTemporal> getListOfAssociatedTPs() {
        return listOfAssociatedTPs;
    }

    public void setListOfAssociatedTPs(List<AssociationTemporal> listOfAssociatedTPs) {
        this.listOfAssociatedTPs = listOfAssociatedTPs;
    }


}
```

Or activites class

```
@Entity
public class Activities extends DataStructure {

        String name;
        List<AssociationTemporal> listOfAsso = new ArrayList<AssociationTemporal>();

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @OneToMany
        public List<AssociationTemporal> getListOfAsso() {
            return listOfAsso;
        }
        public void setListOfAsso(List<AssociationTemporal> listOfAsso) {
            this.listOfAsso = listOfAsso;
        }


}
```

In the main I have added the following:

```
AssociationTemporal at = new AssociationTemporal();

        TP tp1 = new TP();
        TP tp2 = new TP();

        at.setElementA(tp1);
        at.setElementB(tp2);

        session.save(tp1);
        session.save(tp2);
        session.save(at);

        tp1.getListOfAssociatedTPs().add(at);
        tp2.getListOfAssociatedTPs().add(at);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The problem occurs as soon as I try to add the same object of

```
        tp1.getListOfAssociatedTPs().add(at);
        tp2.getListOfAssociatedTPs().add(at);
```

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_12JEPI3MP039NKMGO47YW1HBI_INDEX_A ON PUBLIC.TP_ASSOCIATIONTEMPORAL(LISTOFASSOCIATEDTPS_DATASTRUCTUREID) VALUES (32770, 1)"; SQL statement:
>   insert into PUBLIC.TP_AssociationTemporal (TP_dataStructureID, listOfAssociatedTPs_dataStructureID) values (?, ?) [23505-183]

By the same mean the association can be made with Activities, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just use **GenerationType.SEQUENCE** and it will fix the problem.